# ¿Por que no puedo conectar MySQL Workbench con Java, alguien sabria ver el error?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Se creo una base de datos en local dentro de mysql workbench llamada pruba con la tabla usuarios que incluye dni, nombre y apellidos.

se ejecuta xampp mysql en el puerto 80

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)        at MiBD.main(MiBD.java:82)

[image: introducir la descripción dintroducir la descripción de la imagen aquíe la imagen aquí]

```
// Package db
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.*;

// @author Cristo Rubén Pérez Suárez
public class MiBD {

    // Scanner global
    public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Procedimiento para tomar los datos que se van a introducir a la base de datos
    public static void takeData(Connection conexion) throws SQLException {

        // Se declara las variables que van a almacenar los datos
        String dni, nombre, apellidos;

        // Se vacía el buffer
        sc.nextLine();

        // Pedimos los datos de los usuarios
        System.out.println("Introduzca el DNI: ");
        dni = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Introduzca el Nombre: ");
        nombre = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Introduzca sus Apellidos: ");
        apellidos = sc.nextLine();

        // Llamamos al procedimiento y le pasamos los datos para insertar.
        insertQUERY(conexion, dni, nombre, apellidos);
    }

    // Procedimiento que nos hace la query de insert
    public static void selectQUERY(Connection conexion) throws SQLException {

        // Se prepara una consulta
        Statement sentencia = conexion.createStatement();

        // Enviamos la consulta
        ResultSet resul = sentencia.executeQuery("SELECT DNI,NOMBRE,APELLIDOS FROM Usuarios");

        int i = 0;

        // Bucle para mostrar cada fila de datos de la tabla
        while (resul.next()) {
            i++;
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("-------------USUARIO----------");
            System.out.println("--> NIF: " + resul.getString(1) + "\n--> Nombre: " + resul.getString(2)
                    + "\n--> Apellido: " + resul.getString(3));
            System.out.println();
        }

        // Cerramos la sentencia
        resul.close();
        sentencia.close();
    }

    public static void insertQUERY(Connection conexion, String dni, String nombre, String apellidos)
        throws SQLException {
            // Se prepara la conexion para enviar la sentencia
            Statement sentencia = conexion.createStatement();

            // Creamos la QUERY y mandamos los datos
            sentencia.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO usuarios (dni, nombre, apellidos) VALUES ('" + dni + "','" + nombre + "','" + apellidos + "' )");
        
            // Cerramos
            sentencia.close();
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int opt = 0;

        try {

            // Conexion con la base de datos
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/prueba", "root", "1234");

            System.out.println("Conexion a MySQL");
            System.out.println();

            // Do While para repetir el menu tantas veces como el usuario decida
            do {
                // Mostramos el menu con las opciones
                System.out.println("¿Que desea hacer?");
                System.out.println("    1. Insertar Usuario");
                System.out.println("    2. Listar Usuarios");
                System.out.println("    3. Salir del programa");
                opt = sc.nextInt();

                // Ramificamos cada opcion con un switch
                switch (opt) {
                    case 1:
                        // Llamamos al procedimieto que toma los datos al usuario
                        // Ademas nos llama a la query para insertar los datos
                        takeData(conexion);
                        System.out.println("Datos insertados");
                        System.out.println();
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        // Llamamos al procedimiento que nos realiza el listado
                        selectQUERY(conexion);
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        ;
                        // Cerramos la conexion con la base de datos
                        conexion.close();
                        System.exit(0);
                        break;
                }
                // Valores comprendidos en el switch
            } while (opt > 0 && opt < 4);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ec) {
            ec.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Y esa clase que dice que no encuntra, esta?

Comment: No se ya añadi el drive al classpath pero no funciona

Comment: Qué driver es ese? Esa clase está... Sospechosa

Comment: tengo un documento donde [simulo una tienda realizado con java conectado con mysql](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15iZZOyPlCL8uV5WYusGNVVLHApN4MI2A/view?usp=sharing) a lo mejor te sirve, en la pagina 8 saldrá el siguiente titulo: ``ConexionBdTienda.java`` esa es la conexión

Comment: Bueno el error es claro, no encuentra el Driver para conectarse a la base de datos ¿Agregaste el [driver de mysql](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.29) a tu `pom.xml` o el `.jar` a tu classpath? Por cierto hace RATO (desde Java 6) no hace falta poner  el `Class.forName`

Answer (score 0):

jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/prueba?useSSL=false&useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC

Agrega eso y te deberia funcionar, me pasaba lo mismo. Saludos!